# Joining 2 tables for value comparision

Tags: oracle, join

I have 2 tables which contain data as follows:

```
Table1-
Col1.  Col2
A1.     B1
A1.     B2

Table2-
Col1.  Col2
A1.     C1
A1.     C2
```

Now when I am joining these 2 tables to compare col2, sometimes I get the output like `A1-B1-C1;A1-B2-C2` and some time I get it as `A1-B1-C2;A1-B2-C1`.
But I don't want it to come in the second form ever.can anyone suggest any query which will help me achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you join them? What do you mean by "comparing col2"? With what? Would you mind posting your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) rn 
  from table1 t
) t1 inner join  (
  select t.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) rn 
  from table2 t
) t2 on t2.col1 = t1.col1 and t2.rn = t1.rn
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2d388f7bda97a01009c16e163d326d59).
Results:

```
> COL1 | COL2 | COL2
> :--- | :--- | :---
> A1   | B1   | C1  
> A1   | B2   | C2
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious *join* is on `col1` column which returns 4 rows:

```
SQL> with
  2  t1 (col1, col2) as
  3    (select 'A1', 'B1' from dual union all
  4     select 'A1', 'B2' from dual
  5    ),
  6  t2 (col1, col2) as
  7    (select 'A1', 'C1' from dual union all
  8     select 'A1', 'C2' from dual
  9    )
 10  select a.col1, a.col2 a_col2, b.col2 b_col2
 11  from t1 a join t2 b on a.col1 = b.col1
 12  order by a.col1, a.col2, b.col2;

COL1    A_COL2  B_COL2
------- ------- -------
A1      B1      C1
A1      B1      C2
A1      B2      C1
A1      B2      C2

SQL>
```

These are **all** combinations you named, so - how do you "sometimes" get only two of them, and "sometimes" another two? What's wrong with *another two* results (as you said you don't want them to show at all)?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is to use the `RANK` windows function as follows:

```
SELECT T1C1, T1C2, T2C2 FROM 
(SELECT T1.COL1 T1C1, T1.COL2 T1C2, T2.COL1 T2C1, T2.COL2 T2C2, 
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.COL1 ORDER BY T1.COL2) AS T1RN,  
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.COL1 ORDER BY T2.COL2) AS T2RN
FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1)
WHERE T1RN = T2RN;
```